# Display abbreviated time zone from string representation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone

Let's say I have this string saved as a "time_zone" on my "Event" model.

```
 "America/Chicago"
```

I'd like to convert that value to the abbreviated representation. So, that would ideally look like this

```
"EST"
```

Is there a standard Rails method for making this conversion? I haven't been able to find one.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like we can use:

```
Time.now.in_time_zone(zone).strftime('%Z')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ActiveSupport`

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone["America/Chicago"].tzinfo.current_period.abbreviation.to_s

"CST"
```